# I cannot access PDF files uploaded in the private directory

Tags: files, 9

PDF files uploaded to the private directory cannot be viewed and returns a 404 error.
This also happens to the user with the *Administrator* role.
Other file types can be viewed with no issue.
This issue happens in a production environment, hosted on Cloudways, where the private directory is set from the following line in the *settings.php* file.

```php
$settings['file_private_path'] = $app_root . '/../private';
```

#### Steps to reproduce

- Login to site as administrator user (the one with the *Administrator* role)
- Add a file field to the *Article* content type
- Set its *Upload destination* to *Private files*
- Set *Allowed file extensions* to *txt, pdf, doc, docx* and *Maximum upload size* to 1 MB
- Set the file directory to *article-test* (When the server root directory is *public_html/web*, private files should be uploaded to *public_html/private/article-test*.)
- Create an *Article* node and upload a valid PDF file whose size is less than 1 MB (*doc_0.pdf*)
- Save and publish the node
- View the new node
- Click on the file link for the uploaded file, which links to  `https://<domain>/system/files/article-test/doc_0.pdf`)
- The site returns a 404 error
- The browser bar shows `https://<domain>/user/login?destination=/system/files/article-test/doc_0.pdf` as URL
- Go to `https://<domain>/admin/content/files`
- Click on the file link (`https://<domain>/system/files/article-test/doc_0.pdf`)
- The site still returns a 404 error
- The Drupal log shows *page not found Location `https://<domain>/user/login?destination=%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Farticle-test%2Fdoc_0.pdf`*
- Remove the uploaded file from the node
- Upload a text file or a Microsoft Word file
- Viewing the file doesn't return any 404 error
- viewing the file, a prompts ask for saving or viewing the file

I don't believe this is a permissions issue; otherwise, I wouldn't be able to access these other file types.

The file permissions for the *public_html/private* directory and its directories are set to 775. The file permissions for the uploaded files are set to 664.

Is there a setting (PHP, Drupal, or server) I should change to allow the PDF files to be viewed?

There is an *.htaccess* file in *public_html/private* directory. Thinking it may be related to the issue, I temporarily renamed it to *.htaccess.saved*. I then tried to access the uploaded PDF file, still obtaining a 404 error.

One more fact: If the same exact PDF file is uploaded to the site's public directory, the file can be viewed without errors.

Comment: Drupal serves private files by reading them from the filesystem so I doubt `.htaccess` is anything to do with this. Is the configured directory for private files on a different filesystem than the public directory?

Comment: Some related: https://www.drupal.org/node/2911882

Comment: The private directory is in the same file system as the public directory. This issue  https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3098553 on drupal.org seems to be the solution. I've asked the author for more details on the solution